# Running Chrome Extension On Every New Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

I have created a Chrome Extension that censors data out of your dom. It allows you to add keywords to the `localStorage` and then it hides the parent divs of those keywords and updates the dom with the censored dom.

My problem is if add the keyword on a page, it works and that page is immediately updated.

But if I go to a new page I have to add the keyword again. I need the new tab being viewed to be updated with the censored dom on page load to reduce the amount of times a user has to do anything.

background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
      // First, validate the message's structure
      if ((msg.from === 'content') && (msg.subject === 'showPageAction')) {
        // Enable the page-action for the requesting tab
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
      }
    });

    function loadKeyWords() {
        $('#keyWords').html('');
        localArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyWords'));
        for(var i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
          $('#keyWords').prepend('<li><input class="check" name="check" type="checkbox">'+localArray[i]+'</li>'); 
        $( "div:contains("+localArray[i]+")" ).css( "display", "none" );
        $( "section:contains("+localArray[i]+")" ).css( "display", "none" );
            }
            return localArray;
        }

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  var newURL = "https://www.facebook.com/zensorship";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

   var getKeywords = loadKeyWords();
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(getKeywords)
  }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'custom.js'});
  });
  });
```

custom.js

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var searchValue=config.toString().split(',');
var div;
var j = searchValue.length;
while(j--){
var i = divs.length;
while (i--) {
  div = divs[i];

        if(div.innerHTML.indexOf(searchValue[j]) > -1){

            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

          }
    }
}
```

popup.js

```
// Update the relevant fields with the new data
function setDOMInfo(info) {
  $("div p:contains(localStorage.getItem('keyWords')).parent('div').hide()");
}

// Once the DOM is ready...
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // ...query for the active tab...
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, function (tabs) {
    // ...and send a request for the DOM info...
  document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = 'none';
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        tabs[0].id,
        {from: 'popup', subject: 'DOMInfo'},
        // ...also specifying a callback to be called 
        //    from the receiving end (content script)
        setDOMInfo);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try adding a listener for a page being focused  that loads the keywords again

Comment: You mean like this? document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    document.title = document.hidden; // change tab text for demo
}) If so would you mind showing me to implement this?

Comment: Try this resource https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated

Comment: And you would want that in your background file so that it isn't dependent on your pop up being run

Comment: so would you mind answering the question and showing me how you would implement that?

Comment: Your current code has the listener for it the problem is is that you don't have it set to the current tab you have it set to null

Comment: I would give you a working example but I don't have the time for it right now

Comment: So you mean where it says null change to be current.tab